# Powerpivot model with 2 facttables (?)

Tags: powerpivot

I'm relatively new to Powerpivot, and have a question while working with it (using excel 2013).

The issue is how I should model my data in powerpivot when I have 2 csv files that are facttables and 1 that is a dimension table.

I have a (test)powerpivotmodel sourced from 3 .csv files that I loaded into PowerPivot.

[image: PowerPivot Model]

1. a facttable named expenses (holds the expenses of some person)
2. another facttable named expensesDetails that holds details of an expense-record
3. a dimension table named category that is associated to expenseDetail table

Expenses and ExpensesDetails have pretty much the same information
--> 1 expense record ALWAYS is 1 record in the table expenses and 1 or more records in the expensesDetail table 
--> so an exampel with 1 record in both tables would be an amount that can be fully related to 1 category
--> if 1 amount relates to 2 (or more) categories, in the database there is 1 record in the expense table and 2 (or more) records in the expenseDetail table

The category table is associated to the expenseDetail table.

When I load these 3 tables into powerpivot, with these relations: 
- 1 between expenseDetail and category
- 1 between expenseDetail and expenses

Then 
- I can make a perfect pivot chart when I use fields from expensedetails and category (they are directly linked)
- But when I use fields from both category and the expense table I get incorrect data. 

When I make a sum of expenseAmount by category, the sum is the same for all categories... 
Probably because between those 2 tables the expenseDetails table is located (...)

*-->additionally, excel indicates a mesasage that probably a relation misses...*

How should I fix this in the datamodel?
I was thinking about making a star model with only 1 facttable... But from 2 CSV files with slightly different columns, how can I make 1 facttable of it?

If 1 facttable is not possible, what would be the right way to make the datamodel?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and/or support!

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your model. You cannot combine values from the expense table with the category table because they are not directly related. If you need to be able to view fields from Expense and Category in the same pivot table, you could use the [related function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634202.aspx) to bring those values into the Expense Detail table as calculated columns and then create the measures originally in the Expense table there in Expense Details based off of those calculated columns. You'll probably need to use the [summarize](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492171.aspx) function to make the measures return the appropriate amounts, since these are summarized at the expense level rather than expense details level.